# Only 1 <h1> is Overflowing Out of its container on mobile. The rest of my website looks good on mobile

Tags: python, html, css

I am creating a personal portfolio website and I'm having trouble with my h1 element on only one of the webpages when sizing the page for mobile. It seems that the h1 element text is leaking out of its div container. On all my other pages on the site, that does not happen.

**Here is my my_work.html:**

```
<div class="my-5">
  <div class="p-5 text-center bg-body-tertiary forest-image" style="background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='Images/newforest.jpg') }}); background-size: cover;">
    <div class="container py-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

        <h1>My Projects.</h1>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my my_resume.html:**

```
<div class="my-5">
  <div class="p-5 text-center bg-body-tertiary forest-image" style="background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='Images/newforest.jpg') }}); background-size: cover;">
    <div class="container py-5 col-sm-6">

        <h1>Check Out My Resume!</h1>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And here is my styles.css:**

```
/******************** Main Elements ************************/
.navbar {
background-color: #425F57;; !important;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom:160px;
}



body {
background-color: #C6EBC5;
margin-bottom: 100px;

}


h1 {
font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
font-size: 80px;
color: white;
text-align: center;



}

.under-title {
color: white;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
color: #425F57;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

h3 {
color: #425F57;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

p {
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
color: #454545;
}

.footer-section {
  background-color: #425F57;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;


  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;

}



.footer-tabs {
margin-right: 100px;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;

}

.copyright-words {
margin-left: 100px;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.cards-holder {
background-color: #C6EBC5;
}

.projects-container {
background-color: #C6EBC5;
}

.skills-text {
text-align: left;
width: 75%;
}

.record-link {
color: #425F57;
}

/********************Images******************/

.forest-image {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .forest-image {
   background-position: center top;
  }
  }

.image-frame {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;



}

.image-frame img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;

}

/**************Buttons*******************/

.linkedin {
max-width: 20%;
height: auto;
border: none;
background: none;
}

.linkedin:hover {
background-color: #425F57;


}

.github {
max-width: 20%;
height: auto;
border: none;
}

.github:hover {
background-color: #425F57;
}

.contact-button {
background-color: #425F57;
border: none;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.contact-button:hover {
  background-color: #C4DFDF;
  color: #425F57;

}

.pdf-button {
background-color: #425F57;
border: none;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.pdf-button:hover {
 background-color: #C4DFDF;
  color: #425F57;
}

.contact-button {
background-color: #425F57;
border: none;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.contact-button:hover {
background-color: #C4DFDF;
  color: #425F57;
}


/**********************Cards for Projects******************/


.card-img-top {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
}

.card-text {
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.card-heading {
font-size: 25px;
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.view-code-container {
padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 2px;
}

.skills-used {
margin-top: auto;
text-align: right;

}

.view-code {
  border: none;
  background-color: #425F57;
  color: white;
}

.view-code:hover {
  background-color: #C4DFDF;
  color: #425F57;
}
```

I've searched everywhere and all solutions have failed me. My html code is the exact same for that part of the page on all my pages so I don't understand why this one page is giving me issues.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Which page do you have problems with? Also, you have `col-xs-6` in `my_work.html`.

`col-xs-6` is for screens that are `<576px` according to [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) which means that your HTML is not quite exact in all pages.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm having trouble with the my_work.html. That col-xs-6 was like my last ditch effort to get it to work on mobile haha.

Comment: @TimHendricks It would be even better if you could put your code into a working snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so people can reproduce the code. And probably spot the problem both HTML files.

Comment: I actually resolved this issue just by putting media tags in for the h1 elements. I made each media tag for the font size I wanted for each screen size and that worked!